# Spark Dataframe - How to manipulate rows with nested structure on them?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a spark DataFrame like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
|which_one|  matchID|                                        information|  
+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
|    First|      123|[[1.2, 4.5, 837], [1.4, 4.8, 123], [4.1, 4.7, 143]]|   
|    First|      234|[[4.8, 8.9, 234], [1.1, 4.2, 321], [3.9, 5.7, 521]]|   
|   Second|      345|[[7.7, 8.1, 457], [4.5, 4.9, 345], [1.9, 2.8, 776]]|
+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

for each matchID, I need to find the corresponding list of information. Then, use "which_one" to extract the info I need.

For example, for matchID = 123, it corresponds to [1.4, 4.8, 123]. Then, which_one = "First" means I need the first val 1.4.

for matchID = 234, it corresponds to [4.8, 8.9, 234]. Then, which_one = "First" means I need the first val 4.8.

for matchID = 345, it corresponds to [4.5, 4.9, 345]. Then, which_one = "Second" means I need the second val 4.9.

The result table I want is to add a new column to the end:

```
+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---+
|which_one|  matchID|                                        information|res|  
+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---+
|    First|      123|[[1.2, 4.5, 837], [1.4, 4.8, 123], [4.1, 4.7, 143]]|1.4|   
|    First|      234|[[4.8, 8.9, 234], [1.1, 4.2, 321], [3.9, 5.7, 521]]|4.8|   
|   Second|      345|[[7.7, 8.1, 457], [4.5, 4.9, 345], [1.9, 2.8, 776]]|4.9|
+---------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---+
```

I tried to use foreach and rdd to loop through each row. However, it seems helpless because I cannot find a way to search for the matchID in information column. I searched online for hours without finding useful recourse yet. Any suggestions or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function "explode" can be used for transform  column "information" to array type, and then filter new column by "matchID":

```
val df = Seq(
  ("First", 123, Array(Array(1.2, 4.5, 837), Array(1.4, 4.8, 123), Array(4.1, 4.7, 143))),
  ("First", 234, Array(Array(4.8, 8.9, 234), Array(1.1, 4.2, 321), Array(3.9, 5.7, 521))),
  ("Second", 345, Array(Array(7.7, 8.1, 457), Array(4.5, 4.9, 345), Array(1.9, 2.8, 776))))
  .toDF("which_one", "matchID", "information")

val indexColumn = when($"which_one" === "First", 1).otherwise(
  when($"which_one" === "Second", 2).otherwise(3))

val exploded = df
  .withColumn("exploded", explode($"information"))
  .withColumn("indexColumn", indexColumn)

exploded.show(false)

exploded
  .where(expr("array_contains(exploded, matchID )"))
  .withColumn("res", expr("element_at(exploded,indexColumn)"))
  .drop("exploded", "indexColumn")
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+
|which_one|matchID|information                                              |exploded         |indexColumn|
+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+
|First    |123    |[[1.2, 4.5, 837.0], [1.4, 4.8, 123.0], [4.1, 4.7, 143.0]]|[1.2, 4.5, 837.0]|1          |
|First    |123    |[[1.2, 4.5, 837.0], [1.4, 4.8, 123.0], [4.1, 4.7, 143.0]]|[1.4, 4.8, 123.0]|1          |
|First    |123    |[[1.2, 4.5, 837.0], [1.4, 4.8, 123.0], [4.1, 4.7, 143.0]]|[4.1, 4.7, 143.0]|1          |
|First    |234    |[[4.8, 8.9, 234.0], [1.1, 4.2, 321.0], [3.9, 5.7, 521.0]]|[4.8, 8.9, 234.0]|1          |
|First    |234    |[[4.8, 8.9, 234.0], [1.1, 4.2, 321.0], [3.9, 5.7, 521.0]]|[1.1, 4.2, 321.0]|1          |
|First    |234    |[[4.8, 8.9, 234.0], [1.1, 4.2, 321.0], [3.9, 5.7, 521.0]]|[3.9, 5.7, 521.0]|1          |
|Second   |345    |[[7.7, 8.1, 457.0], [4.5, 4.9, 345.0], [1.9, 2.8, 776.0]]|[7.7, 8.1, 457.0]|2          |
|Second   |345    |[[7.7, 8.1, 457.0], [4.5, 4.9, 345.0], [1.9, 2.8, 776.0]]|[4.5, 4.9, 345.0]|2          |
|Second   |345    |[[7.7, 8.1, 457.0], [4.5, 4.9, 345.0], [1.9, 2.8, 776.0]]|[1.9, 2.8, 776.0]|2          |
+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+

+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+---+
|which_one|matchID|information                                              |res|
+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+---+
|First    |123    |[[1.2, 4.5, 837.0], [1.4, 4.8, 123.0], [4.1, 4.7, 143.0]]|1.4|
|First    |234    |[[4.8, 8.9, 234.0], [1.1, 4.2, 321.0], [3.9, 5.7, 521.0]]|4.8|
|Second   |345    |[[7.7, 8.1, 457.0], [4.5, 4.9, 345.0], [1.9, 2.8, 776.0]]|4.9|
+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about explode before. It definitely solve the problem.